# How can we sort the data in db2 view since "ORDER BY" is not working in view definition?

Tags: sql, view, db2, syntax-error, sql-order-by

Since the `ORDER BY` is not working in create view syntax, how can we sort the outcome data?
I've tried a subselect as below:

```
CREATE VIEW RZKHTNI.VIEW2         
(EMPNO, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME)      
AS SELECT * FROM                               
(SELECT EMPNO, FIRSTNME, LASTNAME  
FROM DSN8910.EMP                  
ORDER BY EMPNO DESC)
```

but I got the error:

> SQLCODE = -104, ERROR:  ILLEGAL SYMBOL "". SOME SYMBOLS THAT
>   MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE: CORRELATION NAME"

So, does anybody have a clue how we can sort the view result?

Comment: If you want results ordered, you need to `order by` in the query that uses the view.

Comment: Add a correlation name as suggested in the error message. Like `T` at the end of the statement. Note, that if you select from this view without the `order by` clause, the engine may not sort the result set. In other words the sort operation may be removed silently in such a case.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me as it is:

```
$ cat 1.sql

CREATE VIEW RZKHTNI.VIEW2
(EMPNO, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME)
AS SELECT * FROM
(SELECT EMPNO, FIRSTNME, LASTNAME
FROM DB2INST1.EMP
ORDER BY EMPNO DESC);

$ db2 -tvf 1.sql

CREATE VIEW RZKHTNI.VIEW2 (EMPNO, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) AS SELECT * FROM (SELECT EMPNO, FIRSTNME, LASTNAME FROM DB2INST1.EMP ORDER BY EMPNO DESC)

DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this won't guarantee the result of `SELECT whatever FROM RZKHTNI.VIEW2` will be returned in any particular order. Only `ORDER BY` in the outermost `SELECT` would guarantee that.